# Avoid overwrite of UMD script

Tags: javascript, webpack, umd

We have a library that's packed using webpack UMD configuration:

```
output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  library: 'MyLib',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
}
```

if the customer includes the js twice it generates a lot of errors probably due referencing issues.
How do I check if the library has been already included and in that case I don't replace the global variable again?